# Inserting a newline in a multiline zsh command pulled from history

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

Sometimes I use multiline commands in `zsh`:

```
❯ echo \
> a \
> multiline \
> command
```

When editing the command after pulling it from a history search, I can change the content of individual lines. However, I can't figure out how to insert another line:

```
# I want to insert another line after "multiline"...
❯ echo \
> a \
> multiline \  # but hitting <return> here just runs the command, even though there's a backslash at the end of the line
> command
```

How can I insert a newline in the middle of a multiline command pulled from history?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6620/how-to-edit-command-line-in-full-screen-editor-in-zsh

Comment: @chepner Awesome, this is great. Pls make an answer where you explain a bit more so I can accept it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `self-insert-unmeta` to bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to insert a literal newline without accepting the command:

```
bindkey '^[^M' self-insert-unmeta
```

To use your example: Hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> at the cursor position (`#`)

```
% echo \
a \
multiline \#
command
```

will get you this:

```
% echo \
a \
multiline \
#
command
```

This works not only when editing history, but also when typing commands. So you can prepare several commands in a script like fashion and accept them with a single <kbd>Return</kbd>.

For example pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> instead of `#` in this example:

```
% echo command 1#
echo command 2#
echo command 3
```

will do the same thing as the command `echo command 1; echo command 2; echo command 3` and produce this output:

```
command 1
command 2
command 3
```

Comment: I know we shouldn't thank people on Stack Overflow but I feel compelled to. Thank you :D I can now create a zsh keybinding that creates a multi-line command (with a here document) and make execution-time changes to it without it printing `heredoc>` and preventing me from editing it, like so: `bindkey -s "^[t" 'sh <<EOF ^[^Mecho "compilation step 1 (optional)"; ^[^Mecho "compilation step 2 (mandatory)"  ^[^MEOF^[[A^[[A^[[H'`

Comment: For some reason this already works for me without doing anything. (Using Ubuntu 18.04+oh-my-zsh)

Comment: This didn't work for me on MacOS 10.12.6, iTerm 3.2.7beta4

Comment: When using the zsh-vi-mode plugin with oh-my-zsh, this key binding seems to be getting clobbered/deleted after being set in my startup file. (After starting a new terminal, it fails to show up in `bindkey`, but still works if I type `bindkey '^[^M' self-insert-unmeta` directly into the command line.) One workaround that works is to only make this key binding available in the vi insert mode keymap: `bindkey -M viins '^[^M' self-insert-unmeta`. @adaephon, thanks for getting me 90% of the way there.

Answer (score 56):

You can use <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>Return</kbd>.

FWIW, I tested it on Debian Jessie, zsh 5.0.7 and it works there.

Answer (score 7):

(A summary of answers from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6620/how-to-edit-command-line-in-full-screen-editor-in-zsh)

`zsh` comes with a function that can be used to open the current command line in your favorite editor. Add the following lines to your `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -z edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey "^X^E" edit-command-line
```

The first line loads the function. The second line creates a new widget for the Z shell line editor (`zle`) from the function of the same name. The third line binds the widget to <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>. If you use the `vi` bindings rather than `emacs` key bindings, use something like

```
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

instead (which binds the widget to <kbd>v</kbd> in `vicmd` mode).

Comment: Your answer is really good, but I have to change the accepted answer since @Adaephon answers it more directly.

Comment: This commands has completely messed up my terminal. Please provide commands how to undo these settings?

Comment: @saumilsdk You may use `stty sane` any time your terminal has messed up capabilities. I do believe it might fix your problem.

Comment: Nothing here affects terminal settings. This is purely configuration of `zsh`'s line editor.

Answer (score 4):

If using `bindkey -v` mode, you can also use the default <kbd>o</kbd>/<kbd>O</kbd> commands from `vicmd` mode to add a newline line and enter `insert` mode in it, respectively above or below the current line.

Answer (score 2):

Just to note, if you want to comment in a multiline command, you could use:

```
❯ echo `#first comment` \
 a `#second comment` \
 multiline \
 command
```

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + Enter (Return) for Windows/WSL
CTRL +X CTRL+E for Mac

Edited as per the comment below

Comment: What actually worked for me on MacOS was `Ctr+X Ctr+E` - so holding the `Ctr` button press `X` and then `E` keys.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an appropriate place to use a shell script file instead no?

```
#!/bin/zsh
my
commands
here
I can even add a new line at a later time.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I disagree. If you are running many variations of a program with a complex command line interface, the shell's history search provides an excellent way to search through and fork off of your previous runs. You don't get this if you store each configuration in a file.